# SQL Date Format - Display the time difference as X days X hours X mins

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, date-format

I wanted to display the difference between 2 timestamps in the format like '`X days X hours X mins'` (e.g. `2 days 2 hours 3 mins`).

The best I can do now is `date_trunc('minutes',sysdate)  - date_trunc('minutes',createdate::timestamp) as age`, which gives me the result like `1 day 06:05:00`. And then I do the extract with the following to get the each part. Then I can concat them..

```
extract(day from age) as days_age,
extract (hour from age) - 24 * extract(day from age) as hours_age,
extract (min from age) - 24 * 60 * days_age - 60 * hours_age,
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to combineto use Redshift function DATEDIFF.

Example to retrieve the number of day between 2 timestamps:

```
DATEDIFF('day', timestamp1, timestamp2)
```

DATEDIFF returns a BIGINT, so depending on the expected result you may cast it to string to concatenate it with the 'minute' part and so on, or do something else.

For example, to get

> 2 days 2 hours 3 mins

:

```
DATEDIFF('day', timestamp1, timestamp2)::text | ' days ' | DATEDIFF('hour', timestamp1, timestamp2)::text | ' hours ' | DATEDIFF('minute', timestamp1, timestamp2)::text | ' minutes'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html